# Custom dash style in NSBezierPath

Tags: cocoa

Is it possible to create a custom dash style for NSBezierPath?

i.e. I want a line of say, arrows all pointing in the direction of the stroke.

For example, something like this...

->--->--->--->--->

Any ideas appreciated..

MT

Answer (score 1):

Not the way you depicted it - the "dash style" is given in "line visible/line not visible" segments. You won't get a "custom brush" type of effect with NSBezierPath as it is.